# Query quartz for existing triggers using criteria

Tags: java, api, quartz-scheduler, scheduler

I am using quartz to schedule jobs. Jobs are created in a "default" group and related information is passed as payload in form of a jobdetail map when using the schedule api.

```
Trigger trigger = new Trigger(...);
JobDetail jobDetail = new JobDetail(...);
jobDetail.put(...);
scheduler.schedule(trigger, jobDetail);
```

I want an API to be able to query the triggers in the database based on the payload sent in. For instance, I have "externalId" as part of the jobDetail.

I want to do something like

```
scheduler.getTriggers(new Criteria("externalId", externalId));
```

instead of fetching all the triggers in memory and then iterating over it. I searched a bit online but wasn't able to find an API to do the same.

EDIT: As of quartz, 2.1.5, there are a few new APIs

```
scheduler.getTrigger(triggerKey(jobId, jobGroupName)); // which can fetch the exact trigger given the triggerKey
scheduler.getTriggerKeys(GroupMatcher.triggerGroupContains(JOB_GROUP_NAME)); //this searches all the triggers for a group.
```

These are not available for quartz 1.8 though. One limitation still is that trigger searches need to be exact and cannot be LIKE % in nature

Answer (score 1):

you can list all you tasks in quartz and collect the required

try this code (jsp):

```
SchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory(new File(getServletContext().getRealPath("/"), "WEB-INF/quartz.properties").getAbsolutePath());
Scheduler scheduler = sf.getScheduler();

try{
    List<JobExecutionContext> jobList = scheduler.getCurrentlyExecutingJobs();

    out.print("<h3>Current tasks: "+jobList.size()+"</h3>");
    for(JobExecutionContext jec : jobList){
        out.print("<hr>");
        JobDetail jobDetail = jec.getJobDetail();
        Trigger trigger = jec.getTrigger();
        TriggerState state = scheduler.getTriggerState(trigger.getKey());
        %>
        <table style="width: 400px; background-color: #ffffff;">
            <tr style="height: 23px;">
                <td style="width: 190px;">
                    class:
                </td>
                <td style="width: 210px;">
                    <b><%=jec.getJobInstance().toString()%></b>
                </td>
            </tr>    
            <tr style="height: 23px;">
                <td>
                    descr:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <i><%=jobDetail.getDescription()%></i>
                </td>
            </tr>                    
            <tr style="height: 23px;">
                <td>
                    next fire time:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%=new Timestamp(trigger.getFireTimeAfter(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())).getTime())%>
                </td>
            </tr> 
            <tr style="height: 23px;">
                <td>
                    prior:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%=state.toString()%>
                </td>
            </tr>                 
        </table>
        <%
    }
}catch(Exception ex){
    out.print(ex.getMessage());
}

out.print("<hr>");

// getting all tasks
try{
    List<String> jobGroups = scheduler.getJobGroupNames();

    out.print("<h3>Triggers: "+jobGroups.size()+"</h3>");
    for (String jName : jobGroups){
        GroupMatcher<JobKey> matcher = GroupMatcher.groupEquals(jName);
        Set keys = scheduler.getJobKeys(matcher);
        Iterator iter = keys.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()){
            JobKey jk = (JobKey)iter.next();
            JobDetail jobDetail = scheduler.getJobDetail(jk);
            // JobDataMap jobDataMap = jobDetail.getJobDataMap();

            List<? extends Trigger> triggers = scheduler.getTriggersOfJob(jk);
            for(Trigger t : triggers){
                out.print("<hr>");
                TriggerState state = scheduler.getTriggerState(t.getKey());
                %>

                <table style="width: 400px; background-color: #ffffff;">
                    <tr style="height: 23px;">
                        <td style="width: 190px;">
                            group/class:
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 210px;">
                            <b><%=t.getJobKey().toString()%></b>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="height: 23px;">
                        <td style="width: 190px;">
                            descr:
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 210px;">
                            <i><%=jobDetail.getDescription()%></i>
                        </td>
                    </tr>                        
                    <tr style="height: 23px;">
                        <td>
                            curr time:
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <%=new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())%>
                        </td>
                    </tr>                        
                    <tr style="height: 23px;">
                        <td>
                            next fire time:
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <%=new Timestamp(t.getFireTimeAfter(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())).getTime())%>
                        </td>
                    </tr>                          
                    <tr style="height: 23px;">
                        <td>
                            prior:
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <%=state.toString()%>
                        </td>
                    </tr>                         
                </table>

                <%
            }
        }
    }
    out.print("<hr>");
}catch (SchedulerException ex){
    out.print(ex.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quartz stores `JobDetails` in a serialized map (`JobDataMap`) format. Unless `deserialization` it is hard to know what are the actual contents of the map.

In your case, I think there is no direct way, You may need to find a work around something like, storing job data map values into separate table which will have `Trigger id` associated with it, but I am not sure how salable this solution would be.

Comment: yes, I wanted to know whether there was a direct API. Managing the data in the application doesn't seem like a good idea. thanks.